# python: split a string containing unwanted whitespaces

Tags: python

Hi I want to two elements from string but my string has whitespaces at the beginning.

How can I split it with elimanting whitespaces from beginning?

```
str = '       ex ex'
element =  str.split(' ',1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str.lstrip()
```

Will strip white space from the left of the string only.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and don't add a separator then leading and trailing whitespaces will be discarded. If you add the `maxsplit` parameter only leading whitespaces will be discarded. No need to use `strip` here.

```
>>> print(' aa bb cc dd  '.split())
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']
>>> print(' aa bb cc dd  '.split(maxsplit=1))
['aa', 'bb cc dd  ']
```